# I need to extract multiple excel data into their own cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet with multiple names in 1 cell. I need each name to be in it's own cell so I can clean it up for a mailing list. I hoping there is a formula to do this as right now I have to manually type it out.

```
ANGELA M & CAROLE J HILMER RALPH A & CAROLE J HILMER
ARREDAVE B BOTELLO BARRERA
ANDRIA C BASS KEVEN R ACOSTA
```

Comment: How is Excel supposed to know what is a name?  Also, how big is the list?  Unless it's massive, it might take less time to do it manually since this is an easy task for a human familiar with the names.

Comment: I am just looking for a formula to extract all the data from 1 cell and place each word into it's own cell. From there I can clean it up. These spreadsheets run from 500 rows of data to over 5000.

Comment: Text To Columns will do that.  Note, though, that it overwrites the original cell as the first output cell so it's a good idea to copy the data to another work area and do it there.

Comment: @Blake, it's unplanned task,,, since names are different and delimiters between each First, Lats & middle so quite unusual & difficult to make a common formula. If possible separate each name with COMMA or DASH so formula to extract or Text to Column can be used ,, my suggestion is edit the post otherwise it may attract Down Vote!!

Comment: @RajeshS, It is impossible to separate each name with comma or dash. The names in the post are actual data that I copied from my spreadsheet to show the differences in the data. I am downloading the data from the county tax records and that is how they give me the data. How can I edit the post to not get down votes? Thanks for your response though. I appreciate any help and feedback.

Comment: Tell me **ANGELA M & CAROLE J HILMER RALPH A & CAROLE J HILMER** ,, whta I'm getting are `3 Names` separated by `& sign` in `One Cell` or `in 3 Cells`, and you want them into one Cell !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand this correct, each name is separated by a new line or a "&"-sign.

Is the list/dataset located in an Excel spreadsheet today? If so, try this:

1. Mark all the data
2. Navigate to the *Data* tab
3. Select *Text to
   Columns*
4. Choose *Delimited*
5. Check *Other* and type *&*
6. Press *Finished*

You will now have all your names in their own cells and columns. You might need to move them to column A or whatever you desire. A little bit manual, but quick and efficient. Requires zero programming.

If you wish to split on each *space* or any other character, just check that option in the *Text to Columns* wizard.

Comment: @Blake No problem! Hope it solves your issue :)

Answer (score 1):

programming solution - This will fill more fields than desired but it will work:
let's say in col. A you find names and delimiters. In col. AA you type a zero. Starting with col. AB enter a find formula to find the delimiter in col. $A starting at position given in previous col..

You are able to fill your cols

```
D        | E | F       | G       | H | I ...
ANGELA   | M | &       | CAROLE  | J | HILMER ...
ARREDAVE | B | BOTELLO | BARRERA |   |
ANDRIA   | C | BASS    | KEVEN   | R | ACOSTA
```

But I doupt this will really help. As Rajesh S wrote your data quality is extraordinarily poor as for many a cell the meaning of the word will be unclear, so start changing this if ever possible.